# Opening element on top of others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of images and text. By default, only the image is showing. When the user clicks the image, it should expand over the others and show the text. Currently it's partly working.

http://jsfiddle.net/kbHfH/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://www.bnl.gov/today/intra_pics/2012/01/Intel-Logo-110px.jpg" alt="">

        <p class="logotext">
            ...
        </p>
    </div>
    ....
```

If you click the leftmost icon in the top row, it will do what I want. There are some problems though.

- When you click any of the icons, the other elements will slide one place closer to the top leftmost corner because the clicked element moves out of it's place due to the absolute positioning. The sliding effect doesn't really show up in the example in JSFiddle because I used same images for all the elements.
- If you click any other icon, it will expand correctly, except it goes to the leftmost corner in the top row. It should expand all the way to the left (like it does now) but it should go any higher. If the clicked item isn't the first one in the row, it should still expand the same amount to the left. Clicking it again should get it back to it's original position.
- You should be able to open multiple at the same time. If you have one opened and you open another one the previously opened element should collapse to it's default state.

I have messed with this a long time. I hope I have provided enough details to get help and to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ukK9s/) that I think satisfies all of the requirements.

The main problem with your demo is that [`.offsetParent()`](http://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/) actually returns an jQuery object and not a *position*, so when setting the CSS of the absolutely positioned element with:

```
$(element).css({
    marginLeft: position.left + "px",
    marginTop: position.top + "px",
    position: "absolute",
    boxShadow: "0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)"
});
```

`position.left` and `position.top` are undefined. If you use `var position = $(element).position();` instead it will return the expected values. However, after doing this, any logo that was opened then closed was being left on the page! Furthermore, since the positioned *logo* shared the same `.logo` class it created further problems with multiple "left over" logos on the page being clickable.

So my approach was to [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the logo and position it over the top, animate it open, then remove it from the DOM once closed. I've heavily commented the JavaScript which should explain in more detail. I've also used the newer [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event binding approach instead of `.click()` to reduce the amount of event handlers, since you are using jQuery 1.7+. I register 2 click event handlers, one for the `.logo` class and one for the `.openLogo` class so that *open* logos are isolated from the main click event handler.

I am not going to re-post all of the HTML here as the only change I made was to remove the `<div id="clear"></div>` from the end.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://www.bnl.gov/today/intra_pics/2012/01/Intel-Logo-110px.jpg" alt=""/>
        <p class="logotext">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://www.bnl.gov/today/intra_pics/2012/01/Intel-Logo-110px.jpg" alt=""/>
        <p class="logotext">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://www.bnl.gov/today/intra_pics/2012/01/Intel-Logo-110px.jpg" alt=""/>
        <p class="logotext">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://www.bnl.gov/today/intra_pics/2012/01/Intel-Logo-110px.jpg" alt=""/>
        <p class="logotext">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container
    .on('click', '.logo', function() {
        var $logo = $(this); // wrap in jQuery once

        // close any already open logos by triggering the click (see function below)
        $('.openLogo').click();

        if ($('.logotext:hidden', this)) { // if logoText is hidden
            var position = $logo.position(); // get position of clicked on logo 

            // clone existing logo otherwise making an existing one position:absolute would
            // cause all the other logos to reflow inside the container
            var $clone = $logo.clone()
                                // now place it in the same position as the one just clicked on
                               .css({top: position.top + 'px', left: position.left + 'px'})
                               // give it some style
                               .addClass('openLogo')
                               // remove the original style
                               .removeClass('logo')
                               // append our clone to the container
                               .appendTo($container);

            // animate open the clone
            $clone.animate({
                width: '580px',
                height: '160px'
            }, 1000, function() {
                // fade in logoText when animation complete
                $clone.children('p').fadeIn();
            });
        }
    }).on('click', '.openLogo', function() {
        var $openLogo = $(this);

        // fade out text first
        $openLogo.children('p').fadeOut(400, function() {
            // and when complete, animate logo back to original width/height
            $openLogo.animate({
                width: '110px',
                height: '80px'
            }, 1000, function() {
                // now just remove clone from DOM
                this.remove();
            });
        });
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    width: 110px;
    height: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.openLogo {
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.logo, .openLogo {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.logotext {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: -90px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    text-align: justify;
}

body {
    background-color: #00000f
}

#container {
    width: 640px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Awesome job! I updated it a little bit because I wanted it to go all the way to the left side. Your version kept the top leftmost corner in a fixed position. http://jsfiddle.net/ukK9s/2/

Comment: Ah OK, I'll admit I wasn't 100% sure on that part but can see from your update what you mean. Looks good!